# CUDA Function Won't Execute For Loop on Python with Numba

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm trying to run a simple update loop of a simulation on the GPU. Basically there are a bunch of "creatures" represented by circles that in each update loop will move and then there will be a check of whether any of them intersect.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numba import cuda


@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:], uint8[:], float32[:], float32[:], float32, uint32, uint32)')
def update(p_x, p_y, radii, types, velocities, max_velocities, acceleration, num_creatures, cycles):
    for c in range(cycles):
        for i in range(num_creatures):
            velocities[i] = velocities[i] + acceleration
            if velocities[i] > max_velocities[i]:
                velocities[i] = max_velocities[i]
            p_x[i] = p_x[i] + (math.cos(1.0) * velocities[i])
            p_y[i] = p_y[i] + (math.sin(1.0) * velocities[i])
        for i in range(num_creatures):
            for j in range(i, num_creatures):
                delta_x = p_x[j] - p_x[i]
                delta_y = p_y[j] - p_y[i]
                distance_squared = (delta_x * delta_x) + (delta_y * delta_y)
                sum_of_radii = radii[types[i]] + radii[types[i]]
                if distance_squared < sum_of_radii * sum_of_radii:
                    pass


acceleration = .1
creature_radius = 10
spacing = 20
food_radius = 3

max_num_creatures = 1500
num_creatures = 0
max_num_food = 500
num_food = 0
max_num_entities = max_num_creatures + max_num_food
num_entities = 0
cycles = 1


p_x = np.empty((max_num_entities, 1), dtype=np.float32)
p_y = np.empty((max_num_entities, 1), dtype=np.float32)
radii = np.array([creature_radius, creature_radius, food_radius], dtype=np.float32)
types = np.empty((max_num_entities, 1), dtype=np.uint8)

velocities = np.empty((max_num_creatures, 1), dtype=np.float32)
max_velocities = np.empty((max_num_creatures, 1), dtype=np.float32)
# types:
# male - 0
# female - 1
# food - 2
for x in range(1, 800 // spacing):
    for y in range(1, 600 // spacing):
        if num_creatures % 2 == 0:
            types[num_creatures] = 0
        else:
            types[num_creatures] = 1
        p_x[num_creatures] = x * spacing
        p_y[num_creatures] = y * spacing
        max_velocities[num_creatures] = 5
        num_creatures += 1


device_p_x = cuda.to_device(p_x)
device_p_y = cuda.to_device(p_y)
device_radii = cuda.to_device(radii)
device_types = cuda.to_device(types)
device_velocities = cuda.to_device(velocities)
device_max_velocities = cuda.to_device(max_velocities)
update(device_p_x, device_p_y, device_radii, device_types, device_velocities, device_max_velocities,
        acceleration, num_creatures, cycles)
print(device_p_x.copy_to_host()[0])
```

The 1.0 in math.cos and math.sin is just a placeholder for the directions of the individual creatures
I have a surrounding loop executed cycles amount of times. If I try to remove it and only leave the block of code moving the creatures neither p_x, p_y or velocities have changed, even if I add a constant to them. Why not?

Comment: you can't print from a numba for-loop in a cuda.jit function

Comment: Oh, okay. Why aren't the values of the arrays changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two problems:

1. You aren't initializing `velocities`:

   ```
   velocities = np.empty((max_num_creatures, 1), dtype=np.float32)
   ```

   we can fix that for a trivial test with:

   ```
   velocities = np.ones((max_num_creatures, 1), dtype=np.float32)
   ```
2. This isn't the correct array shape:

   ```
   p_x = np.empty((max_num_entities, 1), dtype=np.float32)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   to match your kernel signature:

   ```
   @cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:], uint8[:], float32[:], float32[:], float32, uint32, uint32)')
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   we can fix that with:

   ```
   p_x = np.empty(max_num_entities, dtype=np.float32)
   ```

   and likewise for `p_y`, `types`, `velocities`, and `max_velocities`.  (I imagine some change may possibly be in order also for `radii`, but it's not entirely clear what you intend with that, since it appears you want a multi-dimensional array, but are accessing it in-kernel as a single-dimensional array, AFAICT.  Furthermore, that section of your kernel code is a do-nothing, so it is more or less irrelevant for the problem at hand).

When I make those changes, I get what appears to be rational output:

```
$ cat t9.py
import numpy as np
import math
from numba import cuda


@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:], uint8[:], float32[:], float32[:], float32, uint32, uint32)')
def update(p_x, p_y, radii, types, velocities, max_velocities, acceleration, num_creatures, cycles):
    for c in range(cycles):
        for i in range(num_creatures):
            velocities[i] = velocities[i] + acceleration
            if velocities[i] > max_velocities[i]:
                velocities[i] = max_velocities[i]
            p_x[i] = p_x[i] + (math.cos(1.0) * velocities[i])
            p_y[i] = p_y[i] + (math.sin(1.0) * velocities[i])
        for i in range(num_creatures):
            for j in range(i, num_creatures):
                delta_x = p_x[j] - p_x[i]
                delta_y = p_y[j] - p_y[i]
                distance_squared = (delta_x * delta_x) + (delta_y * delta_y)
                sum_of_radii = radii[types[i]] + radii[types[i]]
                if distance_squared < sum_of_radii * sum_of_radii:
                    pass


acceleration = .1
creature_radius = 10
spacing = 20
food_radius = 3

max_num_creatures = 1500
num_creatures = 0
max_num_food = 500
num_food = 0
max_num_entities = max_num_creatures + max_num_food
num_entities = 0
cycles = 1


p_x = np.empty(max_num_entities, dtype=np.float32)
p_y = np.empty(max_num_entities, dtype=np.float32)
radii = np.array([creature_radius, creature_radius, food_radius], dtype=np.float32)
types = np.empty(max_num_entities, dtype=np.uint8)

velocities = np.ones(max_num_creatures, dtype=np.float32)
max_velocities = np.empty(max_num_creatures, dtype=np.float32)
# types:
# male - 0
# female - 1
# food - 2
for x in range(1, 800 // spacing):
    for y in range(1, 600 // spacing):
        if num_creatures % 2 == 0:
            types[num_creatures] = 0
        else:
            types[num_creatures] = 1
        p_x[num_creatures] = x * spacing
        p_y[num_creatures] = y * spacing
        max_velocities[num_creatures] = 5
        num_creatures += 1


device_p_x = cuda.to_device(p_x)
device_p_y = cuda.to_device(p_y)
device_radii = cuda.to_device(radii)
device_types = cuda.to_device(types)
device_velocities = cuda.to_device(velocities)
device_max_velocities = cuda.to_device(max_velocities)
update(device_p_x, device_p_y, device_radii, device_types, device_velocities, device_max_velocities,
        acceleration, num_creatures, cycles)
print(device_p_x.copy_to_host())
$ python t9.py
[  2.05943317e+01   2.05943317e+01   2.05943317e+01 ...,   3.64769361e-11
   1.52645868e-19   1.80563260e+28]
$
```

Also note that currently you are only launching one block of one thread, but I assume that is not pertinent to your request, currently.

Comment: Thanks, those were some pretty stupid mistakes on my part, sorry. How can I adapt the code to utilize multiple threads? What would be the optimal amount of blocks and threads?

Comment: It should be relatively easy to parallelize this code along the `num_creatures` dimension.  The work per creature appears to be relatively independent.  Right now your code is producing ~1100 creatures, so you would aim for ~1100 total threads, basically eliminating that for-loop from your kernel, and letting the `i` variable be the thread ID.  The choice of blocks and block sizes is not critical.  Since 1100 is still a really small number of threads, I would choose something like around 16 blocks of 64 threads.  Again, still a really tiny kernel, but better than just 1 thread.

Comment: The number of creatures might change, but not within the function. What you mean is this, right?

threadsperblock = 64

blockspergrid = 16

update[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](device_p_x, device_p_y, device_radii, device_types, device_velocities, device_max_velocities,
        acceleration, num_creatures, cycles)

Comment: yes, but the kernel code has to change as well.  if you have more creatures to calculate, that would be "better" from a GPU utilization perspective.  I was just using 1100 because it happened to be what your code computes now.

Comment: What changes would I have to make within the kernel? When I tested the code above it appeared to work fine.

Comment: It does work fine.  It will just be "slow".  Nobody in their right mind would run a CUDA code that does any significant work on a kernel of just a single thread.  But do what you wish of course.  Anyway rewriting the kernel will clutter this answer up, and was not the question you were asking anyway.  I suggest you ask a new question when you have a new question.  It will be cleaner that way.  And I suggest clarifying your usage/intent with `radii` before posting this code again.  It's unclear, to me, anyway.  To ask "how to parallelize" you could also just chop off the 2nd half of the kernel.

Comment: Okay, I will. But one thing, I was referring to the change made in the comment above. Passing in threadsperblock = 64 and blockspergrid = 16 would make it parallelized, right?

Comment: It will spin up 1024 (=64*16) threads instead of just a single thread.  But (if you made no other changes) each thread will execute **the exact same code** which is not what you want.  You want each thread to execute the same code but with different parameters, such as different values of `i`, and that requires changes to the kernel code itself, to remove the for-loop(s) in `i`, and to replace it with a cuda thread index.